# Set Date/Time form field from Silverlight WebResource using .Invoke("setValue")

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamics-crm

I try to set a Date field on my form from inside a Silverlight Web Resource but the form field remains empty:

```
var xrm = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("Xrm");
var page = (ScriptObject)xrm.GetProperty("Page");
var startdate = (ScriptObject)page.Invoke("getAttribute", "scheduledstart");
startdate.Invoke("setValue", DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

While the above code works fine for other field types (string, int, OptionSet, etc.) there seems to be an error in the way I try to set the date value.

---

*Side note: I don't use `dynamic` because it seems not to work when deployed in an MS CRM online environment (but works on-premise).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're formatting the date to a string, so it's trying to pass a string into a Javascript Date field.  Just pass it as a DateTime.  The ScriptObject class is designed to convert properly from .Net to Javascript.  [reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645074%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
startdate.Invoke("setValue", DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch - I really missed the obvious (had checked the msdn references on Marshalling between JS and managed code).